# Why isn't environments/test.rb required when `rake test` is run via custom Rake task?

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-5

For $REASONS, I created a Rake task to paper over `rake test`. However, when I use the wrapper task, config/environments/test.rb is never required and, as a result, undesirable things happen (emails are sent out, the database is dropped, etc.).

(FWIW, `Rails.env` and `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` are still set to `test` in the degenerate case.)

```
namespace :organization do    
  desc "Run unit tests."
  task :unit do
    puts Rails.env # test
    Rake::Task["test"].invoke
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the `:environment` in rake tasks for it to work.

```
namespace :organization do    
  desc "Run unit tests."
  task unit: [:environment] do
    puts Rails.env # test
    Rake::Task["test"].invoke
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not solve the problem. (I'd actually already tried this, among other solutions like creating/adding a task dependency which sets `RAILS_ENV` and `Rails.env` to `test`.)